# get values from dynamically generated drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I'm trying to get all `selected` values from `dropdown` that is being populated after accessing some value from first `select box`(`ajax` call).

here what I've tried so far,

```
$(document).on('change', '#modal', function(){
    obj.push($('#modal').val());
});
console.log(obj);
```

`#modal` is the `id` of newly populated `select` box.

`#make` is the `id` of main `select`.

I've tried these two as well

```
$('#make').on('change', '#modal', function(){
```

and

```
$('#modal').on('change', '#modal', function(){
```

but no luck by far

PS. I'm using `select2`

Comment: So you have `select` with id `make`. When this select changes you are making an `ajax` call and populating another `select` with id `modal`. Now after populating the `#modal select` you want to retrieve the `selected` values from that right?

Comment: @AshrafPurno yes, when `#modal` is populated, get all the values selected in `#modal select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the `selected` values from your `#modal select` in your `ajax success callback` after populating the select.

For example http://jsfiddle.net/99hacq59/

Comment: yes, good sol, but it's just selects the value on the go, but what I want is, to get the selected value of second `select` after populating.

Comment: it populates first, then select some value, then hit button to get that value